# how to modify registry in windows 8.1 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]

Tags: windows

How to make the following changes in the registry. The following details are not clear for me. Can any one explain particularly how to add last line devmgr

With a USB keyboard and mouse connected, configured Device Manager to also show non-present devices by making this change to the registry which requires Administrator privilege and a reboot for the change to take effect: 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment] 
devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices"=dword:00000001

Comment: [How do I add a Windows Registry key?](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001349.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following steps:

1. Run **regedit.exe** as administrator
2. Find the path:**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment**
3. Right-click **Environment**, and click **New**, then **Dword(32-bit) Value**
4. Then right-click the new **Dword(New Value#1)** just created, rename it as **devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices**
5. Then right-click the Dword again, click **Modify...**, and type **1**
6. Click **OK** and exit the **regedit**
7. Reboot the machine

[image]